# ValueError: n_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am trying to run the following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold 
X = ["hey", "join now", "hello", "join today", "join us now", "not today", "join this trial", " hey hey", " no", "hola", "bye", "join today", "no","join join"]
y = ["n", "r", "n", "r", "r", "n", "n", "n", "n", "r", "n", "n", "n", "r"]

skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10)

for train, test in skf.split(X,y):  
    print("%s %s" % (train,test))
```

But I get the following error:

```
ValueError: n_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.
```

I have looked here [scikit-learn error: The least populated class in y has only 1 member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179429/scikit-learn-error-the-least-populated-class-in-y-has-only-1-member) but I'm still not really sure what is wrong with my code.

My lists both have lengths of 14 `print(len(X))` `print(len(y))`.

Part of my confusion is that I am not sure what a `members` is defined as and what a `class` is in this context.

**Questions:** How do I fix the error? What is a member? What is a class? (in this context)

Comment: Please look at my answer for explanation of error. But for solving this, I need to know why you are using StratifiedKFold, and not any other. What's your goal here?

Comment: I have a list of 2163 tweets that I have labeled "n" and "r" (I corrected the typo above...no `"y"` are included). I wanted to replicate the error with a shorter list of `X` and `y`. The idea is to perform 10 fold cross validation on the dataset. That is why I wanted to use `n_split = 10`. And I use stratification because there are 2000 `n` and 163 `y`. I thought keeping these ratio's consistent would be desirable

Comment: Ah ok. In that case, using StratifiedKFold on your original dataset should work.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Stratification means to keep the ratio of each class in each fold. So if your original dataset has 3 classes in the ratio of 60%, 20% and 20% then stratification will try to keep that ratio in each fold.

In your case,

```
X = ["hey", "join now", "hello", "join today", "join us now", "not today",
     "join this trial", " hey hey", " no", "hola", "bye", "join today", 
     "no","join join"]
y = ["n", "r", "n", "r", "r", "n", "n", "n", "n", "y", "n", "n", "n", "y"]
```

You have a total of 14 samples (members) with the distribution:

```
class    number of members         percentage
 'n'        9                        64
 'r'        3                        22
 'y'        2                        14
```

So StratifiedKFold will try to keep that ratio in each fold. Now you have specified 10 folds (n_splits). So that means in a single fold, for class 'y' to maintain the ratio, at least 2 / 10 = 0.2 members. But we cannot give less than 1 member (sample) so that's why its throwing an error there.

If instead of `n_splits=10`, you have set `n_splits=2`, then it would have worked, because than the number of members for 'y' will be 2 / 2 = 1. For `n_splits = 10` to work correctly, you need to have atleast 10 samples for each of your classes.

Comment: What command did you use to get the summary numbers?
class    number of members         percentage

Comment: @Michael For this example, I calculated manually. For a larger array, you can use pandas or numpy which have such functionality.

Comment: Excellent, yes I was wondering if these modules had a summary function like there is in R

Comment: this answer is the most suitable one indeed! was facing the same kind of problem!