# Python sklearn Value Error Target Variable

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, valueerror

I am running following code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,stratify=y,test_size=0.3)
```

Output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-b5740f8ae579> in <module>()
      1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      2 
----> 3 X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,stratify=y,test_size=0.3)

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in train_test_split(*arrays, **options)
   2054                      random_state=random_state)
   2055 
-> 2056         train, test = next(cv.split(X=arrays[0], y=stratify))
   2057 
   2058     return list(chain.from_iterable((safe_indexing(a, train),

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in split(self, X, y, groups)
   1202         """
   1203         X, y, groups = indexable(X, y, groups)
-> 1204         for train, test in self._iter_indices(X, y, groups):
   1205             yield train, test
   1206 

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py in _iter_indices(self, X, y, groups)
   1544         class_counts = np.bincount(y_indices)
   1545         if np.min(class_counts) < 2:
-> 1546             raise ValueError("The least populated class in y has only 1"
   1547                              " member, which is too few. The minimum"
   1548                              " number of groups for any class cannot"

ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

When I am running the exact same set of lines for another Machine Learning Project with different data, it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Additional info related to the shape of the dataframe under consideration:

```
print(data.shape)
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
```

Output:

```
(3047, 33)
(3047, 32)
(3047, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using stratify, number of samples belonging to each class need to be proportional in train and test. But you have a class in your data which have only a single sample. So either that can be in train or test at a time and this breaks the stratify option. Hence the error.

See my other [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313387/valueerror-n-splits-10-cannot-be-greater-than-the-number-of-members-in-each-cla/48314533#48314533) which describes a similar situation with example.