# Splitting the datatset for classification

Tags: python, classification, train-test-split

I am trying to train and test classification model, however, I don't understand why I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: The test_size = 9 should be greater or equal to the number of classes = 11
```

What does this error mean?

My code for splitting the datasets are the following:

```
# Splitting the Dataset:
X_train, _, y_train,_ = train_test_split(filtered_features_FM, y_Cat, stratify=y_Cat)
_, X_test, _, y_test = train_test_split(filtered_features_FM_T, y_T_Cat, stratify=y_T_Cat)
```

The error occurs at the test line.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: n\_splits=10 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313387/valueerror-n-splits-10-cannot-be-greater-than-the-number-of-members-in-each-cla)

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni So, the problem is how I split my dataset? like the split ratio?