# GridSearchCV fit call: ValueError: n_splits=5 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to call GridSearchCV fit and get error. But can't understand this error.

Input:

`X_train.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 6000 entries, 9761 to 7270
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   a       6000 non-null   int64
 1   b       6000 non-null   int64
 2   c       6000 non-null   int64
 3   d       6000 non-null   int64
dtypes: int64(4)
memory usage: 234.4 KB
```

`y_train.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Int64Index: 6000 entries, 9761 to 7270
Series name: result
Non-Null Count  Dtype
--------------  -----
6000 non-null   int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 93.8 KB
```

GridSearchCV call:

```
parameters = {
    "max_depth": [1, 2, 3],
}

cv = GridSearchCV(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(), 
    parameters, 
    cv=5,
    verbose=1,
)

cv.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And I receive error:

```
ValueError: n_splits=5 cannot be greater than the number of members in each class.
```

Why? Please explain this error. Thanks.

Comment: Have you seen the answer to this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313387/valueerror-n-splits-10-cannot-be-greater-than-the-number-of-members-in-each-cla

Answer (score 2):

With `cv=5` you ask for a five-fold *stratified* split to be performed.  This means the percentage of each class is preserved for each split.  The smallest class in your data appears to have less than 5 members so a stratified split is not possible: You need at least 5 members in each class so that at least one can be assigned to every split.  You can take a look at the class distribution with `y_train.value_counts()`.

A quick solution would be to reduce the number of folds, e.g.

```
cv = GridSearchCV(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(), 
    parameters, 
    cv=2,
    verbose=1,
)
```

Alternatively you could perform a non-stratified five-fold split like so

```
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

kf5 = KFold(n_splits=5)
cv = GridSearchCV(
    DecisionTreeClassifier(), 
    parameters, 
    cv=kf5,
    verbose=1,
)
```

For more details on stratified splitting and other forms of cross validation see the [sklearn user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratified-k-fold).

Comment: I have 6000 entries. Why I can't split entries to 5 parts?

Comment: I have added some information to my answer.  Also note that the second approach (using `KFold`) performs a five-fold split.