# how can I train test split in scikit learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, train-test-split

does anyone know what is the problem?

```
x=np.linspace(-3,3,100)
rng=np.random.RandomState(42)
y=np.sin(4*x)+x+rng.uniform(size=len(x))
X=x[:,np.newaxis]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.25,random_state=42,stratify=y)
```

I have this error:

```
ValueError: The least populated class in y has only 1 member, which is too few. The minimum number of groups for any class cannot be less than 2.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter (stratify = y) inside the train_test_split is giving you the error. Stratify is used when your labels have repeating values. Eg: Let's say your label columns have values of 0 and 1. Then passing stratify = y, would preserve the original proportion of your labels in your training samples. Say, if you had 60% of 1s and 40% of 0s, then your training sample will also have the same proportion.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `stratify=y`, you should do without.
Also, have a peek [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43179429/scikit-learn-error-the-least-populated-class-in-y-has-only-1-member).

Comment: Please notice that, in such cases, we flag the question as a duplicate instead of answering it.

Comment: I could not find the option to do so, I don't know if it's still locked for my low reputation or I just could not find it...

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#stratification):

> 3.1.2.2. Cross-validation iterators with stratification based on class labels.
>
> Some classification problems can exhibit a large imbalance in the
> distribution of the target classes: for instance there could be
> several times more negative samples than positive samples. In such
> cases it is recommended to use stratified sampling as implemented in
> StratifiedKFold and StratifiedShuffleSplit to ensure that relative
> class frequencies is approximately preserved in each train and
> validation fold.